# STM32F103 Timer2 not interrupting

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, iar

## Background

I'm relatively inexperienced with the STM32 series, so I'm sure that this is simple and I'm missing a setup somewhere.

I am trying to set up the timer to simply interrupt on an update event, which should be when the counter rolls over at the `TIM2->ARR` value.

- I am currently setting a breakpoint inside the timer interrupt and it is simply not triggering
- I have tried to use other timer modules
- The counter is counting (I can observe through the debugger)
- The registers are loaded appropriately based on the below code
- The `TIM2->SR UIF` (update interrupt flag) is set when the counter rolls over

## Code

```
void TIM_init(void){
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;

    TIM2->PSC = 1000;
    TIM2->ARR = 1000;
    TIM2->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM2->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

    DBGMCU->CR |= DBGMCU_CR_DBG_TIM2_STOP;
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void){
    TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;    // clear the interrupt flag
}
```

I also tried setting the priority grouping as follows, same results:

```
void TIM_init(void){
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;

    TIM2->PSC = 10;
    TIM2->ARR = 1000;
    TIM2->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM2->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG;

    // Enable the Timer2 Interrupts
    uint32_t priorityGroup, priority;
    priorityGroup = NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping();
    priority = NVIC_EncodePriority(priorityGroup, 3, 6);
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, priority);

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

    DBGMCU->CR |= DBGMCU_CR_DBG_TIM2_STOP;
    TIM2->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;
}
```

The project also contains an assembly file `startup_stm32f10x.s`.  An excerpt from that file:

```
__vector_table
        DCD     sfe(CSTACK)
        DCD     Reset_Handler             ; Reset Handler
        DCD     NMI_Handler               ; NMI Handler
        DCD     HardFault_Handler         ; Hard Fault Handler.....
```

which continues on, including the `TIM2_IRQHandler`.  This indicates to me that there is a vector table there.

Comment: Did you include the ISR in the interrupt vector table?

Comment: @Lundin Probably not since I'm not sure where that would be done.

Comment: @Lundin There is a `startup_stm32f10x_ld.s` file that is included within the project that apparently has a reference to the `TIM2_IRQHandler`, is this what you mean?

Comment: Before using interrupts, you need to study interrupts. The vector table is loaded at address 0 and upwards on ARM systems. How to add an ISR inside it depends on your tool chain. ST likely have some manner of app note explaining this. Perhaps the name is already added there, I don't know how your tool chain works.

Comment: @Lundin I am currently using IAR as that is the preference of my organization.  The assembly file contains what looks to me like a vector table.  I will include it above.

Comment: What is the name of the handler?

Comment: Ok, I haven't used IAR in forever. I added the tag to the question, so that someone with up-to-date knowledge can help you.

Comment: @slightlynybbled another problem with the F1xx family is that stack align bit is not set by default. So you need (because you probably do not know if the IAR startup does it) to use the proper attribute when declaring the handler.

Comment: @slightlynybbled Maybe this one will help you http://www.farrellf.com/projects/hardware/2012-08-11_STM32F4_Basics:_Timers_(Part_1)/

Comment: you sure it is an interrupt thing and not a debugger/breakpoint thing?  try setting an led.

Comment: @old_timer I am sure that it is an interrupt thing.  As it turns out, there is nothing wrong with my code, but it has to do with IAR setup that I inherited and the vector table.  The project that I inherited was not well-structured for maintainability and that is a factor as well.  I have convinced my betters that the GCC tools are cheaper and just as good, and I have the interrupt working just fine on those.

Comment: examine the binary, see what address the tool is placing the vector (0x08000xxx) see where the working gcc tools has placed it.  I would still highly recommend turning on an led over a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be an exact solution but more of a suggestion untill someone gives a better solution for you.

**Case 1**: If your task needs only few driver initialization like interrupt and you have enough time, then you can go for obvious reading of the whole initialization chapter, for your case interrupt chapter. Keep an eye for the following points.

- Small foot notes in the chapter.
- See the chapter related to clock for exception
- See the chapter related to Power for exception

In some cases the datasheet writes initialization related information in the clock and power chapter which occasionally caused a desired driver not to function.

**Case 2**: If you need several initialization and lots of development to be done in limited time then here is an alternative approach.

During my work with different kind of µc what I found is that it is better to leave the lower level initialization for the manufacturers, at least at beginning stages. Now a days most of the manufacturers have options where you can create a blank skeleton project online or with some kind of software. For your case it is [STM32Cube initialization code generator](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-configurators-and-code-generators/stm32cubemx.html).

The advantages being you can select your µc and related drivers and they will create a full skeleton project with all initialization and sometimes fill it up with example code for you to start. It reduces developer effort to go through the lower level initialization and directly go for development. You can also see their code to get the grasp of how the driver has been initialized and do relevant modification. Keep a close eye on the comments in their initialization code for understanding or any framework documentation that comes with it.